# Retrieving Image from Firebase Realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

How do I retrieve a specific URL from the real-time database?

[image]

```
 final database = FirebaseDatabase(
    databaseURL:
    "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
    .reference()
    .child('NTU')
    .child(widget.referenceName);
```

.
.
.

```
  Widget _buildItem(String imgPath, String labName, int quantity, String expiry,
  Function onAdd, Function onSubtract, Function onDelete) {
void _minusNum() {
  onSubtract();
}

void _onAdd() {
  onAdd();
}

void _onDelete() {
  onDelete();
}

return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10, top: 0.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: _onDelete,
          child: Row(children: [
            Hero(
                tag: imgPath,
                child: const Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(''),  <---THIS IS THE LINE
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 120.0,
                    width: 130.0)),
            const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                labName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                expiry,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 30.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                    color: const Color(0xFF7A9BEE)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: _minusNum,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 25.0,
                        width: 25.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                            color: const Color(0xFF7A9BEE)),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.remove,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(quantity.toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 15.0)),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: _onAdd,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 25.0,
                        width: 25.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            color: Color(0xFF7A9BEE),
                            size: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]),
          ]),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

}

.
.
.

```
tag: imgPath,
                child: const Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(''),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 120.0,
                    width: 130.0)
```

I am able to retrieve the rest of the item in the firebase, but I am unable to retrieve the Image.

The error appears:

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///lists%5Bindex%5D%5B%22Image%22%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really clear, but This error is definitely happening because you're assigning an invalid image link `''` to your `NetworkImage`.

Comment: From my understanding, when I retrieve the image link with lists[index]["Image"], I then pass the retrieved URL into NetworkImage. I am able to retrieve the other items besides the image tho

Comment: let me get this clear, what you are trying to is when you get "Image" field in your document, you would use it to retrieve other data like "Quantity"?

Comment: When I get ''Image " field, which is an URL. I would like to display the URL image. which is done with NetworkImage. Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the full code.

Comment: Oh I see, you need to put this url in your `NetworkImage` like:

 `image: NetworkImage(url)`

but in your code the you're leaving `NetworkImage` empty

Comment: is there a way i can put the retrieve url from 'Image' to NetworkImage?

Comment: yes as I mentioned above you do so like this:

`Image(image: NetworkImage(theRetrievedImageURL)`

instead of :

`Image(image: NetworkImage('')`